# Class helper in C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, class-helpers

I am wondering whether there is a function named `Class Helper` even for C++ Builder.

My Environment:
RadStudio XE4 Update 1.

I found explanation for Delphi in RadStudio XE4 [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Category:Delphi_Language_Guide)

I searched similar page for C++ Builder [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Keywords,_By_Category_Index), but do not find information for Class Helper for C++.

How can I find whether or not there is the `Class Helper` for C++ Builder on the help page? Are there any page showing the lists of functions for C++ Builder/Delphi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Class and Record Helpers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers) are Delphi features, there are no equivalents in C++.